# Trying to parse Word Documents and getting PdfReadError: EOF marker not found

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am testing some Python code to loop through resumes, open each, parse each, and create a comprehensive report based on the contents of each resume.  Here is the code that I am running.

```
#importing all required libraries

import PyPDF2
import os
from os import listdir
from os.path import isfile, join
from io import StringIO
import pandas as pd
from collections import Counter
import en_core_web_sm
nlp = en_core_web_sm.load()
from spacy.matcher import PhraseMatcher

#Function to read resumes from the folder one by one
mypath='C:\\path_to_resumes\\' #enter your path here where you saved the resumes
onlyfiles = [os.path.join(mypath, f) for f in os.listdir(mypath) if os.path.isfile(os.path.join(mypath, f))]

def pdfextract(file):
    fileReader = PyPDF2.PdfFileReader(open(file,'rb'))
    countpage = fileReader.getNumPages()
    count = 0
    text = []
    while count < countpage:    
        pageObj = fileReader.getPage(count)
        count +=1
        t = pageObj.extractText()
        print (t)
        text.append(t)
    return text

#function to read resume ends


#function that does phrase matching and builds a candidate profile
def create_profile(file):
    text = pdfextract(file) 
    text = str(text)
    text = text.replace("\\n", "")
    text = text.lower()
    #below is the csv where we have all the keywords, you can customize your own
    keyword_dict = pd.read_csv('D:/NLP_Resume/resume/template_new.csv')
    stats_words = [nlp(text) for text in keyword_dict['Statistics'].dropna(axis = 0)]
    NLP_words = [nlp(text) for text in keyword_dict['NLP'].dropna(axis = 0)]
    ML_words = [nlp(text) for text in keyword_dict['Machine Learning'].dropna(axis = 0)]
    DL_words = [nlp(text) for text in keyword_dict['Deep Learning'].dropna(axis = 0)]
    R_words = [nlp(text) for text in keyword_dict['R Language'].dropna(axis = 0)]
    python_words = [nlp(text) for text in keyword_dict['Python Language'].dropna(axis = 0)]
    Data_Engineering_words = [nlp(text) for text in keyword_dict['Data Engineering'].dropna(axis = 0)]

    matcher = PhraseMatcher(nlp.vocab)
    matcher.add('Stats', None, *stats_words)
    matcher.add('NLP', None, *NLP_words)
    matcher.add('ML', None, *ML_words)
    matcher.add('DL', None, *DL_words)
    matcher.add('R', None, *R_words)
    matcher.add('Python', None, *python_words)
    matcher.add('DE', None, *Data_Engineering_words)
    doc = nlp(text)

    d = []  
    matches = matcher(doc)
    for match_id, start, end in matches:
        rule_id = nlp.vocab.strings[match_id]  # get the unicode ID, i.e. 'COLOR'
        span = doc[start : end]  # get the matched slice of the doc
        d.append((rule_id, span.text))      
    keywords = "\n".join(f'{i[0]} {i[1]} ({j})' for i,j in Counter(d).items())

    ## convertimg string of keywords to dataframe
    df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(keywords),names = ['Keywords_List'])
    df1 = pd.DataFrame(df.Keywords_List.str.split(' ',1).tolist(),columns = ['Subject','Keyword'])
    df2 = pd.DataFrame(df1.Keyword.str.split('(',1).tolist(),columns = ['Keyword', 'Count'])
    df3 = pd.concat([df1['Subject'],df2['Keyword'], df2['Count']], axis =1) 
    df3['Count'] = df3['Count'].apply(lambda x: x.rstrip(")"))

    base = os.path.basename(file)
    filename = os.path.splitext(base)[0]

    name = filename.split('_')
    name2 = name[0]
    name2 = name2.lower()
    ## converting str to dataframe
    name3 = pd.read_csv(StringIO(name2),names = ['Candidate Name'])

    dataf = pd.concat([name3['Candidate Name'], df3['Subject'], df3['Keyword'], df3['Count']], axis = 1)
    dataf['Candidate Name'].fillna(dataf['Candidate Name'].iloc[0], inplace = True)

    return(dataf)

#function ends

#code to execute/call the above functions

final_database=pd.DataFrame()
i = 0 
while i < len(onlyfiles):
    file = onlyfiles[i]
    dat = create_profile(file)
    final_database = final_database.append(dat)
    i +=1
    print(final_database)


#code to count words under each category and visulaize it through Matplotlib

final_database2 = final_database['Keyword'].groupby([final_database['Candidate Name'], final_database['Subject']]).count().unstack()
final_database2.reset_index(inplace = True)
final_database2.fillna(0,inplace=True)
new_data = final_database2.iloc[:,1:]
new_data.index = final_database2['Candidate Name']
#execute the below line if you want to see the candidate profile in a csv format
#sample2=new_data.to_csv('sample.csv')
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.rcParams.update({'font.size': 10})
ax = new_data.plot.barh(title="Resume keywords by category", legend=False, figsize=(25,7), stacked=True)
labels = []
for j in new_data.columns:
    for i in new_data.index:
        label = str(j)+": " + str(new_data.loc[i][j])
        labels.append(label)
patches = ax.patches
for label, rect in zip(labels, patches):
    width = rect.get_width()
    if width > 0:
        x = rect.get_x()
        y = rect.get_y()
        height = rect.get_height()
        ax.text(x + width/2., y + height/2., label, ha='center', va='center')
plt.show()
```

In the folder, I have '.doc' and '.docx' files.  Everything seems to work fine, up until this point, directly below.  When I get here, the code throws an error.  Here is the troublesome code.  The weird thing is, that it looks like some kind of PDF error, but I'm iterating only through '.doc' and '.docx' files.

```
final_database=pd.DataFrame()
i = 0 
while i < len(onlyfiles):
    file = onlyfiles[i]
    dat = create_profile(file)
    final_database = final_database.append(dat)
    i +=1
    print(final_database)
```

Here is the StackTrace:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-2-c63fca79d39f>", line 5, in <module>
    dat = create_profile(file)

  File "<ipython-input-1-cdc3bf75cd26>", line 34, in create_profile
    text = pdfextract(file)

  File "<ipython-input-1-cdc3bf75cd26>", line 17, in pdfextract
    fileReader = PyPDF2.PdfFileReader(open(file,'rb'))

  File "C:\Users\ryans\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\PyPDF2\pdf.py", line 1084, in __init__
    self.read(stream)

  File "C:\Users\ryans\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\PyPDF2\pdf.py", line 1696, in read
    raise utils.PdfReadError("EOF marker not found")

PdfReadError: EOF marker not found
```

The code comes from here.

https://towardsdatascience.com/do-the-keywords-in-your-resume-aptly-represent-what-type-of-data-scientist-you-are-59134105ba0d

Answer (score 1):

You are using package PyPDF2, which is used to read and manipulate pdf files. In the article from towardsdatascience that you mentioned all resumes that author was working on were in pdf format.

Maybe if your resumes are in doc/docx format you should explore python-docx library:
https://python-docx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html

Comment: Yes, you are right, all files must be in PDF format, not .DOC or .DOCX.  I changed everything to PDF, re-ran the code, and everything worked fine.  Thanks.